# After Install magento 2.4.5 facing issue AutoLoad error

Tags: magento2

Autoload error

```
{$e->getMessage()}
HTML; http_response_code(500); exit(1); } $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */ $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class); $bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: Please try help me

Answer (score 1):

Check PHP version and its require modules

Create a `info.php` file with `phpinfo()` as contents and hit like this url `localhost/mymagento/info.php`

Comment: I am getting the blank page

Comment: checked version in terminal is using php -v 8.1.12

Comment: Link : https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Autoload-Error-on-localhost/td-p/23316

Comment: Thanks, Issue is reslove after install libapache2-mod-php

Comment: Okay, Rajesh...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to access: `{your_base_url}/get.php` ? Does it shows the php code itself ? If yes and if you are running an apache server, you will probably miss this package: `libapache2-mod-php(your wanted php version)`.

In my case, for PHP 8.2 running:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php8.2
sudo a2dismod php8.1
sudo a2enmod php8.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Fixed the issue.