# autoload error after installing Magento website locally

Tags: magento2, apache2

After I installed a website from git and imported the corresponding database i tried getting the website to work locally. But I keep getting the error

```
{$e->getMessage()}
HTML; http_response_code(500); exit(1); } $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */ $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class); $bootstrap->run($app);
```

I looked at the solution from: [After Install magento 2.4.5 facing issue AutoLoad error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367637/after-install-magento-2-4-5-facing-issue-autoload-error)

But I already got the libapache2-mod-php installed.
Some specs:

- Apahce2
- php8.1
- mysql

I've added a screenshot of the error when i go to localhost:
[image]

Comment: Can you please try the solution from the link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164422/magento-2-getting-autoload-error

Or could you please show error screenshot

Comment: @user3411 I've tried setting the permission (and restarting apache2) but I still get the same error. I've added a sreen of the error.